# Problems with twitter bootstrap framework

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

First problem is, I wonder how I can make some div in twitter bootstrap or insert text? Do I do it like usual? `<div>`, `<p>`, `<h1>` or any other tag for text or what? Of course I want that text and divs be responsive.

Second problem is, when I want to style those elements should I make new `style.css` file or put it in existing bootstrap css?

Comment: I recommend you to join this group. http://ell.stackexchange.com/ @mha

Answer (score 3):

A little digging into Bootstrap would go a long way. Please check out [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as you are new and do look at the rest of the topics in the Help Center.

It doesn't look like you've researched or looked into how the framework really works or checked out any examples.

It doesn't reinvent how CSS/HTML work together. DIV's will work the same, but there are classes Bootstrap utilizes to make the structure (see [Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) for more). Basically there is a `container` DIV with a nested `row` DIV and applicable grids inside (like `col-xs-12`, which would fill up the width of a screen at mobile sizes). The grids allow responsiveness when paired with other elements that are [Responsive Utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) such as "visible" (`visible-xs` as an example would make elements visible in mobile) or "hidden" (`hidden-xs` would hide them). Adding `img-responsive` on an image will make it scale to fit the parent grid DIV.

You would still need to follow the convention of adding in meta viewport (see [setup](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started) for a base example) support to activate responsiveness. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` is an example.

Overriding in your own style.css would be best. I prefer utilizing LESS and having a custom LESS file for variable overrides (or if you're not comfortable with LESS and don't anticipate changes in the future to update your Bootstrap version, you can use the [Customize Page](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) to output your own preferences in a compiled CSS file).

Comment: I probably still don't get this part but thanks for rest. Adding this class col-xs-12 would make some element weight 100% of screen size? Through all 12 columns or? And would col-xs-6 mean that it going to be 50% size only or? :/ I probably didn't get it well?

Comment: Correct. It's based on a 12-column grid by default, so the number (1 through 12) next to the breakpoint size (xs, sm, md, lg) is relative to how many columns the DIV will consume.

Comment: Awesome. Last question would be when I want to use javascript/jquery is it included in boostrap.js or I should install it like I do normally? Thanks for answers!

Comment: `<MATA name="viewport">`does **not** *activate* responsiveness. Proper bootstrap layout will be responsive without it.  This tags controls the *appearance* (width/scale) of a site content on small screens.

Comment: @PM77-1 I know that. I didn't put in the meta code completely. It was a broad reference. I linked to bootstrap documentation because you need their base HTML structure to get the js too. The question the op has is too broad to warrant specifics.

Comment: I just wanted to clarify the usage of the tag.  Sometimes it's presented as [`Responsive Meta Tag`](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/) which got me initially confused.

Comment: `bootstrap[.min].js` requires but does not include jQuery.